# how can i make a db_query call in page.html.twig in drupal 8?

Tags: mysql, drupal

I am trying to call some fields from database in my custom page twig.
When i clear cache it throws,website encountered an unexpected error.
Can you give any tip on how this is made on `drupal` 8?

Comment: The purpose of twig is to separate the front with the back (in an attempt from drupal 8 to get closer to mvc model), so you can not execute PHP code. Even in drupal 7, making requests in a template file was a really bad practice, use a hook preprocess like suggested Sunil.

Answer (score 1):

twig template does not support direct php code , 1st you have to hook_page_preprocess() and implement it on your template , you can check https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/group/themeable/8.2.x
Thanks